# Cross-platform local port forwarding solution

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, portforwarding, openvpn

I am building a SaaS service which needs to query some data from its user's APIs. Typically user enters a url like `mydomain.com/endpoint` and service makes requests. However, for some users the endpoint is in their local network behind NAT (say `mydomain.local/endpoint`)

My idea is to give users **the easiest, cross-platform and open-source solution** to forward a local port (like 80 or 443) to my server. Done that, I can make queries from server to `localhost:12345/endpoint`

I can imagine a number of solutions like setting up a vpn (using openvpn) or employing ssh port forwarding (by sshing from local to server with `ssh -f -N -R 12345:mydomain.local:80 server.com`). However the question is which solution will be the most easy to use for non-professional users.

Ideally, I see it as a cross-platform app (Windows, Max OS, and Linux versions), which is pre-configured by me to talk to my server, get a local url and a desired server-side port (like `mydomain.local` and `12345` in examples above) and start forwarding.

**Update to clarify my question**: I'm asking for advice and suggestions which solutions/technologies should I consider in attempt to solve my problem.

Comment: If the users are making the connection, then their routers will automatically forward the port for the connection as long as the connection is open. You cannot from the server open a port on the remote router, and each router model has a different way to do that, generally requiring manual intervention because it is creating a permanent to the router NAPT table.

Comment: Of course I cannot open a connection to local resource from the server side. Let me explain what I mean. Say `S` is my server, `C` is user's computer, `R` is a resource in user's LAN. I cannot make a connection from `S` to `R`. However I can make a connection from `C` to `R`, and also `C` can connect to `S`, and I can set up `C` to make a tunnel between `C` and `S` and do port forwarding. For example, I can ssh from `C` to `S` as specified in my question, and after that local port 12345 on `S` will be forwarded to port 80 on `R` via the tunnel.

Comment: What I'm seeking for is the most easy and user-friendly way to achieve it. Ideally with zero-configuration from user side, just run it and it works (assuming I already know local IP address and port of `R` and I can make an API at `S` returning these values)

Comment: OK, but you seem to be asking for us to come up with something for you. Asking for the -est (best, easiest, etc.) leads to being off-topic as seeking primarily opinion-based answers, or it could be off topic as a recommendation. You need to give your work, not ask for someone to give you their work.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not sure I understood you. Isn't StackOverflow the proper place to ask for advice? I'm not asking for someone to do the work for me, I'm wondering if there are approaches, libraries and utilities that I'm not aware of. I added a clarifying update to my question, hope it helps.

Comment: Asking for resource recommendations, such as libraries or tools is off-topic here. From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: You seem to be squeezing my question out of StackOverflow and I respect your opinion. However, I still believe this question relates to _a specific, practical and answerable problem that is unique to software development_ so I will keep it in hope to get on-topic replies.